# Destruction of bound dependent types

Tags: coq, dependent-type, equality

I'm having an issue with dependent typing. I have reduced it to the following minimal example:

```
Require Import Arith.
Require Import Equality.

Inductive Ex (n : nat) :=
  | X : Ex n.

Definition Cast (n : nat) {n'} 
  (eq : n = n') (e : Ex n) : Ex n'.
Proof.
  destruct eq.
  exact e.
Defined.

Lemma dim_help {x y} (H: x =? y = true) : x = y.
Proof.
  apply Nat.eqb_eq; easy.
Defined.

Definition test {dim} (n : nat) : Ex dim.
  destruct (n =? dim) eqn:H.
  + apply (Cast _ (dim_help H)).
    apply (X n).
  + apply (X dim).
Defined.

Lemma test_lemma : forall n, @test n n = X n.
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold test.
Abort.
```

In the following code my goal in `test_lemma` works out to be

```
(if n =? n as b return ((n =? n) = b -> Ex n)
 then fun H : (n =? n) = true => Cast n (dim_help H) (X n)
 else fun _ : (n =? n) = false => X n) eq_refl = X n
```

Intuitively I'd like to destruct over `n =? n` however that yields the error

```
fun b0 : bool =>
(if b0 as b1 return (b0 = b1 -> Ex n)
 then fun H : b0 = true => Cast n (dim_help H) (X n)
 else fun _ : b0 = false => X n) eq_refl = X n
which is ill-typed.
Reason is: Illegal application: 
The term "@dim_help" of type "forall x y : nat, (x =? y) = true -> x = y"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "n" : "nat"
 "n" : "nat"
 "H" : "b0 = true"
The 3rd term has type "b0 = true" which should be coercible to
 "(n =? n) = true".
```

Is there a way to work around this issue? How can I destruct the equality to do case analysis over `test`?

Comment: `Ex n` is equivalent to `True`. Are you sure this is what you intend?

Comment: This is just a reduced minimal example to show issues with the handling of specific proof terms. It is not an actually used proof script. However, the answer still applies to our proof script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coq simply tells you that when it is trying to
do a case on `n ?= n` in the expression

```ml
(if n =? n as b return ((n =? n) = b -> Ex n)
 then fun H : (n =? n) = true => Cast n (dim_help H) (X n)
 else fun _ : (n =? n) = false => X n) eq_refl = X n
```

your argument `eq_refl` does not vary as needed :
it should be a proof of `(n =? n) = true` in the first case and a proof of `(n =? n) = false` in the second case. There is no way `eq_refl` will meet this,

You can fix this with a simpler definition of `test`

```ml
Definition test {dim} (n : nat) : Ex dim.
  destruct (Nat.eq_dec n dim) as [e|e].
  + apply (Cast _ e).
    apply (X n).
  + apply (X dim).
Defined.
```

Then you are left with proving

```ml
forall e : n = n, Cast n e (X n) = X n
```

which can be done because unicity of identity proof holds in Coq for natural numbers. so we have

```ml
forall n (e : n = n), e = refl_eq n.
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! This is exactly what I was looking for